# Xtext Content Assist not triggered by CTRL+SPACE inside the Orion web editor

Tags: xtext, eclipse-orion

I am trying to use Xtext (2.14.0) together with the Orion web editor, but even with a simple example the Content Assist is not triggered by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> inside the Orion editor.

From what I know, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> is used by default to trigger the Content Assist inside the Orion editor.

I also want to mention that if I add a character to the **"contentAssistCharTriggers"** option (as described in the Xtext documentation), than the specified character triggers the Content Assist, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> still doesn't work.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Update:
I am using the basic xtext state machine example.
Below is the html file used to embed the Orion Editor:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
 <title>Example Web Editor</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dependencies/orion/code_edit/built-codeEdit.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xtext/2.14.0/xtext-orion.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 <script src="webjars/requirejs/2.3.2/require.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var baseUrl = window.location.pathname;
  var fileIndex = baseUrl.indexOf("index.html");
  if (fileIndex > 0)
   baseUrl = baseUrl.slice(0, fileIndex);
  require.config({
   baseUrl: baseUrl,
   paths: {
    "text": "webjars/requirejs-text/2.0.15/text",
    "jquery": "webjars/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min",
    "xtext/xtext-orion": "xtext/2.14.0/xtext-orion"
   }
  });
  require(["dependencies/orion/code_edit/built-codeEdit-amd"], function() {
   require(["xtext/xtext-orion"], function(xtext) {
    xtext.createEditor({
     baseUrl: baseUrl,
     syntaxDefinition: "xtext-resources/generated/mylang-syntax",
     contentAssistCharTriggers: " "    
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <h1>Demo</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <div id="xtext-editor" data-editor-xtext-lang="mylang"></div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you provide a minimal repoducible example? did you examine the javascript console for errors?

Comment: I've updated my post with more information. There are no javascript errors in the console. From what I saw, when CTRL+SPACE is used to trigger the Content Assist, it looks like the content assist providers are not bounded to the Orion Editor. You can check this in the build-codeEdit-amd.js file if you set a break point on "setState" function (line 39719) and check the "_mode" property of the ContentAssist object. You will see that it is "undefined" when you use CTRL+SPACE. Also, if you use the character specified in the "contentAssistCharTriggers" , the "_mode" property is set correctly.

Comment: this is why i ask for a "complete" example (github/gitlab/...)

Comment: which orion version did you pick. what happens if you start with a non empty file

Comment: means:type one space. the content assist

Comment: I've added the example to github (https://github.com/andrewsandu/xtext-web-example.git). I'm using Orion codeEdit 18.0. Even if I start with a non empty file, CTRL+SPACE is not working.

Comment: i type space the crtl+space and get content assist.

Comment: which browser do you use

Comment: Chrome. The issue is the same in Firefox and IE. Does CTRL+SPACE  trigger the content assist at the beginning of the file ?

Comment: as is said: i have to type one space to get content assist working

Comment: i dot know what happens without your customizations.... but there it works for me if the file has contents or i type one space and then crtl+space

Comment: In my project I have to use CTRL+SPACE as a trigger. How could I fix it ?

Comment: i dont understand what is your goal for content assist. on space (works with your code) or on crtl+space (see below)

Comment: My goal is to use CTRL+SPACE to trigger the content assist, instead of other characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the index html that works fine for me (content assist with crtl+space)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <title>Example Web Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="orion/code_edit/built-codeEdit.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xtext/2.14.0/xtext-orion.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="webjars/requirejs/2.3.2/require.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var baseUrl = window.location.pathname;
        var fileIndex = baseUrl.indexOf("index.html");
        if (fileIndex > 0)
            baseUrl = baseUrl.slice(0, fileIndex);
        require.config({
            baseUrl: baseUrl,
            paths: {
                "text": "webjars/requirejs-text/2.0.15/text",
                "jquery": "webjars/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min",
                "xtext/xtext-orion": "xtext/2.14.0/xtext-orion"
            }
        });
        require(["orion/code_edit/built-codeEdit-amd"], function() {
            require(["xtext/xtext-orion"], function(xtext) {
                xtext.createEditor({
                    baseUrl: baseUrl,
                    syntaxDefinition: "xtext-resources/generated/mydsl-syntax"
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Example MyDsl Web Editor</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="xtext-editor" data-editor-xtext-lang="mydsl">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is how your stuff looks like

[image]

Comment: I've tried your code, but again CTRL+SPACE is not working

Comment: which codeedit did you download i used. http://download.eclipse.org/orion/drops/R-12.0-201606220105/built-codeEdit.zip

Comment: I used this one: http://download.eclipse.org/orion/drops/R-18.0-201804181410/download.php?dropFile=built-codeEdit.zip

Comment: the one i used the the one the official samples use

Comment: I've tested with your codeEdit version and is working fine. Xtext 2.14.0 doesn't support code edit 18.0 ?

Comment: there was no contribution done that did any update for codeedit, ace and codemirror so i assume no

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Updating requirejs to 2.3.6 and jquery to 3.3.1-1 make codeEdit with you version work.
We updated everything in Xtext 2.17 that will come in spring 2019.

Comment: Orion got broken since version 18.
We nailed the version to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/orion/drops/R-17.0-201801111044/built-codeEdit.zip and issued bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543541.